# I need to stop an infinite while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop, break, execute-immediate

while the script is running, it needs to be outside the input to catch the keyword and break the loop, I need to break the loop instantly with the 'esc' word, while the script waits for input by the user

¿how do i that?

```
import time ; import keyboard as kb

while (True):
    if kb.is_pressed('esc'):
        break
    n = str(input('f(x) = '))
    print(n)
    time.sleep(1)
```

its a bit whim but the only way to stop the loop is to hold the 'esc' keyword and it would be more comfortable to press the key and instantly break the loop, i tried a few methods but they all lead to the same thing and this one is the most efficient

Comment: Maybe remove the `sleep`, `input` already slows loop execution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop an infinite loop safely in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922909/how-to-stop-an-infinite-loop-safely-in-python)

Comment: If you don’t mind changing the key, you’ll find that Ctrl+C will stop the loop immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>esc</kbd>, you can just catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` error.

```
import time

while True:
    try: 
        n = str(input('f(x) = '))
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nBreaking from the infinite loop")
            break
```

`SIGINT` is the signal sent when we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The default action is to terminate the process. However in Python, a `KeyboardInterrupt` error is raised.

It can be difficult to trigger a `SIGINT` when the escape key is pressed, since the interrupt process is hardware and OS dependent.